# Using XPath 1.0 String functions to alter returned attribute using .net

Tags: .net, string, function, xpath

<Edit>Originally I was using slashes in my example and was not escaping them correctly - this was a red herring as the underlying problem is still there<\Edit>

<Edit>I've added simple code at the base of this question which demonstrates the issue, without any slashes</Edit>

I'm working within a system which is relatively fixed and which provides xpath as a query language.  The system is based on .net 4.5.

I'm attempting to join two sets of data.  The first set of data is in the form:

```
Aa1
Aa2
Aa3
etc
```

The second set of data is in the form:

```
Ab1
Ab2
Ab3
etc
```

I've attempted to manipulate the first dataset I've got back by doing the following:

```
someContextNode.SelectSingleNode("../translate(@reference,'a','b')")
```

...but I get the following error:

```
XPathException: '../translate(@reference,'a','b')' has invalid token.
```

Fine, fine: so, as I'm only after a single result, I tried:

```
someContextNode.SelectSingleNode("translate(../@reference,'a','b')")
```

... but I get the following error:

```
XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

Reading up, this seems to be a limitation of Xpath 1.0; If I has xpath 2, I could tokenize.

My question is: Is there a dodge for this (being able to manipulate outputs) I've not found, as it seems to be quite a fundamental weakness in Xpath 1.0.

Example code which reproduces the issue:

```
    Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    doc.LoadXml("<Data reference=""Aa1""><Subnode /></Data>")

    Dim startNode As System.Xml.XmlNode = doc.ChildNodes(0).SelectSingleNode("Subnode")

    Dim trans1ex As System.Exception = Nothing
    Try
        Dim trans1 As System.Xml.XmlNode = startNode.SelectSingleNode("translate(../@reference,'a','b')")
    Catch ex As Exception
        trans1ex = ex
    End Try
    Dim trans2ex As System.Exception = Nothing
    Try
        Dim trans2 As System.Xml.XmlNode = startNode.SelectSingleNode("../translate(@reference,'a','b')")
    Catch ex As Exception
        trans2ex = ex
    End Try

    Dim trans3 As System.Xml.XmlNode = startNode.SelectSingleNode("../@reference")

    Stop
```

At the end of executing this code, the two local exception objects will contain objects which are as described above.  The local trans3 object will successfully point to an attribute node.  I believe that the issue with both exceptions is that SelectSingleNode isn't expecting a function, it's expecting a node.  My question is (assuming I'm not doing anything stupid), is it possible using .net and xpath 1 to dodge this in some way by using a different xpath expression?

Comment: What does your XML data actually look like? What's inside the `reference` attribute?

Comment: Don't you have to escape the antislash?

Comment: @Kilazur As it happens the issues which would arise due to not escaping the backslash are unlikely to be the issue.  I've tested with swapping the slashes for a's and b's and have the same issues.  Will edit the question now to remove this area of confusion.

Comment: Please answer my question above and show the XML.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Done, and thank you for looking at this!

Comment: Sure that `SelectSingleNode("Subnode")` works? Why not `SelectSingleNode("//Subnode")`? Also, I have edited my answer with some more speculation :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
someContextNode.SelectSingleNode("translate(../@reference,'/','\\')")
```

The problem is the following. A backslash is a special character that needs to be escaped in a string. XPath does not define its own escaping rules, but follows closely the rules laid out by the host language (in your case, C#).

Otherwise, your XPath expression is fine. I tested it with XSLT, of course following the escaping rules of XSLT. Other sources of error might be

- that you are using `someContextNode.SelectSingleNode()` in the wrong way.
- that the XML you are querying does simply not make sense for this expression. More precisely, there might not be an element node whose parent element has an attribute `reference` that contains a string with forward slashes.

---

**EDIT**: As a response to your question edit.

Now I have reason to suspect that you are indeed using `SelectSingleNode()`in the wrong way. But first let us look at the first expression you have tried:

```
"../translate(@reference,'a','b')"
```

An expression like this is invalid in XPath 1.0 because a function (`translate()`) is not allowed as a step in a path expression. But a function can deal with a path expression as an argument, and that's the second expression you have tried:

```
someContextNode.SelectSingleNode("translate(../@reference,'a','b')")
```

That expression is fine in both XPath 1.0 and 2.0. The problem is now at a different level: `SelectSingleNode()` is expected to return a set of nodes, not a string.

Or put another way, this is not a limitation of XPath 1.0, this is a limitation of your .NET environment. Perhaps there are methods other than `SelectSingleNode()` that evaluate an XPath expression and that have a different return type?

It is a weakness of XPath 1.0 that it lacks certain ways to manipulate data, but after all it's meant to be a query language, to *find* things, not to manipulate them.

Comment: I've amended the question - although the escaping may have been a problem, .net wasn't getting that far

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding using another method within the .net framework to get the result of the translate - this may be the case, but I'm operating within a framework where the query mechanism available to me is only SelectSingleNode.  I'll take it to be impossible using .net and Xpath 1.0